# Question Editing and keeping Scope in Mind

Tags: discussion, edits

I understand there is a fine line when editing questions, mostly because in some cases there is too little information, too little information of substance, or too much information that doesn't contribute to the question.

When you are editing such a question, what is the best way to approach such a beast?

Currently I do:

- Try to interpret the best I can.
- If I feel my edit will lose scope of the question I flag for a Moderator.

Because there have been instances where the question is too vague and an edit will lose the proper meaning.  Other times an edit should occur to adhere to Stacks Policies, but I feel the meaning will be lost.

Is that the best approach, as it should be closed?

Or my interpretation wasn't correct and now doesn't adhere to the original writers goal.  But it still falls into this above limbo of not adhering to Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, understand the question you're editing. This can be the most difficult part.

Then write that question in a way that's easy to read, constructive, and generally makes the author sound like a reasonably competent human being.

If you can preserve some of the original tone when doing this... bonus!

Try not to mess with the code too much though. As tempting as it can be to fix all those syntax errors...

Comment: Valid points, that is where this fine line is.  You believe you understand the question but it isn't written in the authors original intent so it loses that meaning.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't feel like you comprehend the question well enough, you should likely do nothing except down vote or vote to close, if so inclined and able. Obviously, you should not try to edit a question when you don't understand it.

If it's that difficult to understand, yes; a close vote is appropriate.

Note, however, that a Moderator flag is probably not the proper thing to do in these cases. The community can handle 'moderating' such posts.

Comment: What if you lack the reputation to close?  Just down vote to get Moderator attention? Thank you for the answer Andrew, and good luck in your Moderator election.

Comment: Flag, and choose "it doesn't belong here", @Greg.

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you very much for that explanation, makes sense.  I'd like to keep the community rich and do my fair share to help so all this advice just helps.